# Load Java WindowBuilder design from other class

Tags: java, swing, windowbuilder

I use the Java WindowBuilder to create some windows. To see always how the designed window looks like.

Now I have a program where I code the menu code to an extra `MenuHelper` Java class. Because my main window class has too much code. But now if I watch at the design there is no menu because the WindowBuilder uses only the code in the window Java class.

Can I import extern classes to the WindowBuilder or must I code at any time the code for Swing components to the main WindowBuilder class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since WindowBuilder generates source code in a set structure it will try to find the relevant code in a similar structure. Because of that, all UI related code should remain in the class it was generated.

To reduce the amount of code in the UI class you could (and should) write the logic for anything that isn't directly related to UI changes in separate classes.